# How to remove "Post?a=" from URL in CI

Tags: php, continuous-integration

I would like to remove **Post?a=** this from url.

Current URL : http://localhost/apn_new/Post?a=contact.php
I want : http://localhost/apn_new/contact.php

htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?a=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Also I have try to replace **Post?a=** using php

```
$url = 'http://localhost/apn_new/Post?a=ftp_server.php';
$my_var = 'Post';
$url = str_replace("Post?a", '/' . $my_var . '/', $url );
```

did not working.  I'm Using Conditioner. Please help me. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've a typo in your str_replace:

```
$url = 'http://localhost/apn_new/Post?a=contact.php ';
$url = str_replace("/Post?a=", '/', $url );

//output is http://localhost/apn_new/contact.php
```

You can also use mod rewrite, post your apache version for more info

Answer (score 1):

in PHP for remove Post?a= from url  you can use this :

```
$url = str_replace("Post?a=","", $url );
```